# What is idiomatically the best word to use for "friendly" when applying to the sentiment of a competition?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

It can be slang.  I don’t want it to be formal.  Here is the sentence I want to translate (but I really just need the word “friendly” done):

> With you, this competition is fun.  Like a race, but almost **friendly**.

Answer (score 5):

You have the adjective ***amistoso, a***, a word that you can use at all levels, both in formal and informal contexts. It has [the following meaning](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2MteLWd), explicitly saying that it is used to speak about friendly competition:

> Dicho de un encuentro deportivo: Que no es de competición.

It is very common in Spanish to talk about *partidos amistosos*, *encuentros amistosos* and so on, so you can certainly say:

> Contigo, la competición es divertida. Como una carrera, pero casi amistosa.

If you want a slang term, be aware that slang words tend to suffer from regional variations. For instance, you may substitute *amistoso* with *de colegueo* (derived from *[colega](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9l4ZtQ5)*), but probably you will be understood only in Spain.

You can also use in Spain the expression *de buen rollo*, but then drop the *casi*:

> Como una carrera, pero de buen rollo.

We use this expression when we want to convey the feeling of something having a good vibe.

Comment: Is *buen rollo* panhispanic?  I strongly associate it with peninsular Spanish but maybe I just haven't paid enough attention.

Comment: @guifa I doubt so, I just forgot to mention that "buen rollo" is also an expression from Spain, but we could ask that in the site...

Comment: @guifa - I don't think it is, but from the context, body language, etc., one could probably get the gist.

Comment: @Charlie also..

Answer (score 3):

The term used for friendly competitions is "[**amistoso**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=2MteLWd)", like in "[partido amistoso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partido_amistoso)".
These friendly matches are played outside any official competitions and so are supposed to be more fun and less serious; however, due to the natural competitiveness of sports players, more often than not "amistoso" matches end up being not-so-friendly :/

If I were you and wanted to convey the meaning of a fun and friendly competition, I would use "**partido [benéfico](https://dle.rae.es/?id=5Lgp4JY)**": the kind made to rise funds for something. Now these are just a type of "amistoso", but in *these* kind of matches / races / whatever it doesn't matter who wins, so players use to leave some of their competitiveness aside and just have fun :)

So, if somebody said to me:

> Fue como jugar un partido **amistoso**.

I would understand that it was a normal match, but with an irrelevant result.
However if someone told me:

> Fue como jugar un partido **benéfico**.

I'd definitely understand that it was a fun and friendly match.

You could also use [pachanga](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ROsZqkH), which means specifically "an informal, friendly match of soccer, basketball or other sports".